# Convert Byte Array to PDF File IOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, pdf, nsdata

I have the following code to call the webservice that returns `byte[]` for PDF File. 
Is there something wrong ? it is generating the corrupt PDF file.

**More Details**

IOS send request for the pdf file through Webservice which is written in .Net Framework. The webservice returns Array of Bytes for the PDF File. Now what i need to do is capture the Array of Bytes and convert it into PDF file in IOS.

The following piece of code is my try to do that

```
@try {
    NSString *baseURL = @"http://host/service/GetPDF";

    NSLog(@"Service URL : %s\n", [baseURL UTF8String]);
    NSURL *serviceURL = [NSURL URLWithString: baseURL];

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: serviceURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30.0];

    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError = NULL;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

    NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];        
    NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];

    NSData* pdfData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[responseData bytes] length:[responseData length]];
    [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];     
}
@catch (NSException* ex) {
    NSLog(@"doSomethingFancy failed: %@",ex);
}
```

Comment: what's exception message show in Log?

Comment: No exception.. It writes the file to the location. But i could not open the file as it says "The file pdf.pdf could not be opened". It may be damaged or use a file format that is not recognized"

Comment: Can you add that extra information into the question for us?

Comment: some extra info added hope this helps